# What are these warning / error messages which appear at the Arch Linux login prompt?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, console

When I boot into the text login for my Arch Linux box, sometimes various messages are displayed such as:

```
Arch Linux 4.7.1-1-ARCH (tty1)

hermes login: [    3.975371] radeon 0000:03:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110),
_
```

I do have a Radeon video card, so I am assuming that this message is related to that. However since this is just one of a few various messages I have seen across various machines, I am more interested what process is running which writes that message, and whether or not they get logged somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages are part of the log messages written during the boot process.
You can see the complete log messages with the following command:

```
dmesg | less
```

Comment: For anyone who wishes to disable these messages from appearing at the login prompt, try adding "quiet loglevel=3" to the end of your kernel parameters. See [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot)